# Erlang can't find OpenSSL library in Windows

Tags: erlang

I'm struggling compiling Erlang from source on a Windows machine. Everything goes well to the point where `./otp_build` script tries to find OpenSSL library. Even though I have installed `cygwin32-openssl-1.0.1e-1` and `cygwin32-openssl-1.0.1e-1` it still says that it can't find OpenSSL in standart locations. Any tips what the standard location of OpenSSL is? the command `whereis openssl` points to the correct location of binaries.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you want the windows OpenSSL install, not the Cygwin one. It should be downloadable from the OpenSSL website.

Comment: In fact now it should be also compiled on windows as there are no downloadable binaries anymore